# What is wrong with my code urlopen function?

Tags: python, urllib

Below is my python code to check curse word in the file.
But i am unable to find why the compiler is showing error: `module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlopen'`.

```
import urllib
def read_txt():
   quote = open("c:\\read.txt")  #for opening the file

   content = quote.read()  #for reading content in a file
   print(content)
   quote.close()  #for closing the file
   check_profanity(content)


def check_profanity(text):
   connection = urllib.urlopen("https://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q=" + text)
   ouput = connection.read()
   print(output)
   connection.close() 
read_txt()
```

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3, [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) is now a package that collects multiple modules. [`urlopen()` is now a part of `urllib.request` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
```

Then using it:

```
connection = urlopen("https://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q=" + text)
```

Comment: thank you sir for helping .I made that mistake by checking online source for python 2.x

Answer (score 1):

Well, because `urllib` does not have a `urlopen` method.

In Python2 you should use `urllib2`, while in Python 3 you should use `urllib.request`